# Why doesn't [:blank:] work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table which one of its columns is a comma-separated string of tags. I used `REGEXP` to select all the entries that contains the input tag, but at first it didn't work.
Following is the query that I first tried which only returned true for tags at the beginning of the string.

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tags REGEXP '(^|,[:blank:]*)some tag([:blank:]*,|$)'
```

Since I only assume spaces between tags and commas, I tried using ' ' (space) instead.

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tags REGEXP '(^|, *)some tag( *,|$)'
```

This worked as I expected. However, according to the documentations, it looked like `[:blank:]` matchs whitespaces. My question is why it didn't work as I expected. I'm using MySQL 5.6.10.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but I'll recommend you to remove space between tags at the save, to improve the speed of your query (it's king of heavy to select entries with regex...).
Even better, you should create a real relationnal database with an other table where tags are stored with foreign keys

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just recently started teaching myself MySQL along with PHP, so that didn't occur to me. I will modify my tables, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation I see they use double brackets:

```
 SELECT 'justalnums' REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]+';
```

Example from here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html

Comment: gee I feel like I asked a dumb question! Thank you though!